# Anonymous Class in Java

Tags: java, class, anonymous

Is it possible to create an anonymous class in Java like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    AnonymousClass a = new AnonymousClass() {
        int whatever = 1;
    };

    System.out.println(a.whatever);
}
```

I thought that this would be working but it doesn't. Do I misunderstand something with anonymous classes or is there only a syntax error?

Comment: *What* doesn't work? You should really post the error!

Comment: If you haven't defined `AnonymousClass`, it won't work!

Answer (score 4):

You *can* do it this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new Object() {
      int whatever = 1;
    }.whatever);
}
```

That is, you can only dereference the fields and method directly from the instantiation expression. [*Edit:* Per the comments, you can use it where the compiler infers the type for you - which happens to be the instantion expression, or as a return value from a generic method you pass it to.] You can't store it in a variable and use fields/methods there, so it's not as useful as anonymous classes in e.g. C#.

**Edit:** You can, as previously stated by others, declare a method-local class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    class Local {
      int whatever = 1;
    }
    Local local = new Local();
    System.out.println(local);
}
```

Slightly wordy, though, and like non-static inner classes and regular anonymous classes, it retains an implicit reference to the enclosing `this` (in non-static methods).

Comment: @gustafc: anonymous classes also retain an implicit reference to the outer object. No difference with method-local classes.

Comment: As a point of pedantry, you can do it [slightly] non-directly. Pass it through a method `private static <T> T fn(T value) { return value; }`.

Comment: @JB Nizet - quite right, fixed the post to say what I actually meant. I'll have to blame an oncoming cold for not thinking about that.

Answer (score 2):

For this to work, AnonymousClass needs to be an Interface or a Class:

```
private interface AnonymousClass {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

        AnonymousClass a = new AnonymousClass() {
            int whatever = 1;
        };

    System.out.println(a.whatever); // this won't work
}
```

**EDIT**

Corrected, as correctly stated in the comment, `whatever` won't accessible / present.

Comment: It won't compile, `a.whatever` is not visible.

Comment: Except the print statement wouldn't work. `a` is of type AnonymousClass (the interface), which doesn't specify the presence of `whatever`.

Answer (score 2):

If it was possible, we would not call them anonymous anymore: your example defines a class with a name: `Anonymous`. You may define an inner class with a name like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    class NotAnonymous {
        public int whatever = 1;
    }
    NotAnonymous na = new NotAnonymous();
    System.out.println(na.whatever);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referring  original anonymous class instance, which has no field "whatever" - so you can not reference it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your class like this, sure. However, the `a.whatever` call will fail, because the object type is still `AnonymousClass`, and it does not define `whatever` as an attribute.

If you overwrite some method or attribute that is already defined in the `AnonymousClass` class or interface, the object will use your implementation from the anonymous class instead of the old one, but not if you introduce new methods or attributes.